# SQL ORDER BY months starting with this month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that returns months 1-12. (INT)

Is there a way to order the results starting on this month desc?

Example

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
1
2
```

Thanks!

EDIT: By this month desc, I mean this actual month. MONTH(GetDate())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simple maths in order by, if month is smaller then current add 12, not sure what will be the performance impact ...

```
Order By Case When month(dateColumn) < month(GetDate()) Then month(dateColumn) +12
ELSE month(dateColumn) END
```

Comment: Assuming we're only dealing with 12 entries, this is also a good solution.

Comment: So what are the other assumptions?

Comment: Not even sure, trying to get more details. Check the comments on my answer.

Comment: I used this - but added DAY(datecolumn) to the order by so it wasn't displayed all random

Answer (score 2):

You can add a year in there for sort purposes. Make them output something like:

```
2010-03
2010-04
...
2011-01
2011-02
```

Pseduo code:

```
WHERE year >= 2010 AND month >= 3
```

Not sure what your query is or the data backing it though.

Comment: I can't add years, it has to remain as a month.

Comment: @user: You can for sorting purposes. Just because you're adding a filter method doesn't mean it has to come across in your result.

Comment: So how would I know which one would be first according to this month?

Comment: @user: You tell me? I don't exactly have a database schema, or even a basic query to go by. You've listed 12 numbers and a destination, up to you to chose the route. (I'm thinking of the numbers 1,5 & 12--make it equal 14 with math [synopsis of my viewpoint])

Comment: The route is starting by todays month MONTH(GetDate()) which would be 3

Comment: @user: And is this based on real data, a loop you're creating, SPROC, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have month column in your table with 1,2,3,---,11,12 values

```
SELECT *, case when `month`>=3 then `month`
          else `month`+12 end as `temp_month`
          FROM `tbl_name` order by `temp_month`
```

You will get output like

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Brad's answer, add a year column, then

```
...
ORDER BY year, month
```

Use ASCending or DESCending sort modifiers depending on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not add years, it is impossible. The reasoning is because there is no way to tell which January or any month came first.

The only solution you have to to simply order them by `YEAR` first, then by `MONTH`.

So unless you change the field into a `DATE` format or include a YEAR column, you can't do anything. Unless you want to arrange them by `ID`; which was entered first.

So in short: No `YEAR` = no way.

Answer (score 0):

Much better in terms of execution cost:

```
Select * From
Group By monthcolumn,firstname,lastname 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,datecolumn) DESC, DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn) DESC
```

Or, this one is a little expensive in terms of execution cost:

```
Select * From
Group By monthcolumn ,firstname,lastname    
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn))=3 THEN 1
              WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn))=2 THEN 2
              WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn))=1 THEN 3
              WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn))=12 THEN 4
              WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn))=11 THEN 5
              WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH, datecolumn))=10 THEN 6
              ELSE 0 END  
              ASC
```