# How can i order my rows from (first) a column and then (secondly) another column which is a specific starting time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table where i need to handle the ordering with two columns. the first one holds the days from 1 to 7. this is the first column to order. and then there is another column that i need to order but this time i need it to start ordering from 06:00:00.

```
    SELECT * FROM stream 
ORDER BY day,start="06";
```

i tried this but i guess i do something wrong.

this is a part of my query result:

```
|  ID | DAY |                          START |                            END | PROGRAM_ID |
|-----|-----|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|------------|
|   1 |   1 | January, 01 1970 06:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 07:00:00+0000 |          1 |
|  13 |   1 | January, 01 1970 18:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 19:00:00+0000 |          5 |
|  14 |   1 | January, 01 1970 19:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 20:00:00+0000 |          6 |
|  15 |   1 | January, 01 1970 20:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 21:00:00+0000 |          6 |
|  16 |   1 | January, 01 1970 21:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 22:00:00+0000 |          6 |
|  17 |   1 | January, 01 1970 22:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 23:00:00+0000 |          7 |
|  18 |   1 | January, 01 1970 23:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:00+0000 |          7 |
|  19 |   1 | January, 01 1970 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 01:00:00+0000 |          7 |
| 163 |   1 | January, 01 1970 10:24:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 10:45:00+0000 |          6 |
|  39 |   1 | January, 01 1970 01:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 06:00:00+0000 |          8 |
|  12 |   1 | January, 01 1970 17:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 18:00:00+0000 |          5 |
|  11 |   1 | January, 01 1970 16:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 17:00:00+0000 |          1 |
|   2 |   1 | January, 01 1970 07:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 08:00:00+0000 |          1 |
|   3 |   1 | January, 01 1970 08:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 09:00:00+0000 |          2 |
|   4 |   1 | January, 01 1970 09:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 10:00:00+0000 |          2 |
|   5 |   1 | January, 01 1970 10:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 11:00:00+0000 |          3 |
|   6 |   1 | January, 01 1970 11:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 12:00:00+0000 |          3 |
|   7 |   1 | January, 01 1970 12:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 13:00:00+0000 |          3 |
|   8 |   1 | January, 01 1970 13:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 14:00:00+0000 |          4 |
|   9 |   1 | January, 01 1970 14:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 15:00:00+0000 |          4 |
|  10 |   1 | January, 01 1970 15:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 16:00:00+0000 |          1 |
|  32 |   2 | January, 01 1970 18:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 19:00:00+0000 |          5 |
|  33 |   2 | January, 01 1970 19:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 20:00:00+0000 |          6 |
```

Actually on my own mysql, i don't get the "January, 01 1970" part. but this is the output of sqlfiddle.anyway i don't think that this will matter for the solution.

here is the sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d57d7d/2/0

Comment: If the ordering starts at 6 AM, how do the rest of the records get ordered?  Do you just want the 6 AM record to appear at the top of each day, and you don't care how the rest of the records are ordered?

Comment: what do you mean by "start ordering from 06:00:00."? can you provide sample data and the required output?

Comment: no i care of the rest as well. it should start from 6AM an continue thru all times until the next day starts.

Comment: So which columns you want to order by? Is it DAY,START?

Comment: What do you do with the times before 6 AM?  Do you throw them out?  Do you put them at the bottom of the stack?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d57d7d/13 this is the currently query that works. here everything works fine. but i want the time start from 6am. like 06..08..11..14..15..16..17..10..22..01..03..05

Comment: I've seen the SQLFiddle.  You didn't answer my question.  *What do you want to do with the records before 6 AM?*

Comment: yes @SOaddict i want it to order first DAY then START but as i said starting from 06AM

Comment: @RobertHarvey i want go thru all the times that are stored. but i want them like this: day1-06:00:00, day1-08:00:00, day1-012:00:00, day1-022:00:00, day1-01:00:00, day1-04:00:00 THEN day2-06:00:00, day2-08:00:00, day2-012:00:00, day2-022:00:00, day2-01:00:00, day2-04:00:00 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add 25 to hour if it is less than 6 in the `ORDER BY` clasue, take a look:

```
SELECT * FROM stream 
ORDER BY day, CASE
                WHEN hour(start) < 6 THEN hour(start) + 25 
                ELSE hour(start)
              END
```

This way, all the values before the `06:00:00` will be at the end.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d57d7d/33

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej what is the +25 for ?

Comment: @Skeletor It works like this: the ordering is based on the hour of the time. To each hour that is less than 6, we are telling MySQL to add a value of 25. This makes all hours before 6 to have a value greater than maximal hour, which is, of course, 24. Thanks to this, all hours before 6 will be put at the end when sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a CASE to your order query, take a look at this post !

```
Order BY CASE 1 THEN ORDER BY CASE 2 ...
```

[Order by Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276038/sql-order-by-months-starting-with-this-month)

Comment: That's a little vague for an answer.  You could probably be a little more specific than just providing a link.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, im new here :) tryin' to help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. If you would like to order by any two columns then try using below options.

```
ORDER BY Column1,Column2;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d57d7d/11
```

Comment: If it were that simple, he would have already figured it out.

Comment: @SOaddict: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731980/how-can-i-order-my-rows-from-first-a-column-and-then-secondly-another-column?noredirect=1#comment29317332_19731980.  He wants to start in the middle, and put the earlier records at the end.

Comment: I understood Robert... Not sure if it can be done with mysql or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey absolutely that was what i meant. i want somehow to change the offset that it is starting to count. I'm not sure too. the values are stored in the mysql as "time" type. i thought that there could be a way when the mysql treats it as a time and perhaps there could be a way to change its starting offset.