# SQL query to get list of months start from current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a `SQL` query to list the months in a year which starts from the current month. 
 I have tried this query, but I need Current month as first in the list.

```
DECLARE @year int
SET @year = 2016
SELECT number AS a,
    DATENAME(MONTH, cast(@year*100+number AS varchar) + '01') AS b
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  WHERE TYPE = 'P'
    AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```

Thank You

Comment: Kindly post the query you have tried.

Comment: And please specify the database.

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL ORDER BY months starting with this month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276038/sql-order-by-months-starting-with-this-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this query.
it's just for demonstration,

```
DECLARE @YEAR INT
SET @YEAR = (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()))
DECLARE @MONTH INT
SET @MONTH = (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()))

DECLARE @DT TABLE(ID INT, MONTHNAME NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @DT SELECT NUMBER AS ID,
   DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(@YEAR*100+NUMBER AS VARCHAR) + '01')  AS MONTHNAME
FROM MASTER.DBO.SPT_VALUES   
WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND  
  NUMBER BETWEEN @MONTH AND 12

INSERT INTO @DT SELECT NUMBER AS ID,
   DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(@YEAR*100+NUMBER AS VARCHAR) + '01')  AS MONTHNAME

FROM MASTER.DBO.SPT_VALUES   
WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND  
  NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND @MONTH -1

SELECT * FROM @DT
```

Comment: I cant pass any arguments,since it wont meet my requirement

Comment: What my requirement is to have a list of months, but the list start from the current month.

Comment: yes, and i do as you required, run the updated code..and if you still have any issue then reply me.

Comment: ok, and where is the issue? can you tale me in more specific so i can give appropriate solution..

Comment: I need a list of months, first in the list should be the current month, no need to pass year too..

Comment: ok, no need to pass year, so what should be the default year. you have to pass a range to stop a list at certain point..or you want a list of infinite months from current month..

Comment: Let the default year be 2016, but it should work for the upcoming years.

Comment: ok, see updated code, now it takes current year as default one.

Comment: But I need Jan,Feb,Mar at the end

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using a recursive cte:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  GETDATE() As TheDate, 
            DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) As TheMonth
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheDate), 
            DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheDate))
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, TheDate)) = YEAR(GETDATE())
)

SELECT TheMonth
FROM CTE
```